# При сворачивании приложения сервисы завершают работу

Tags: java, android

Имею сервисы медиаплеера и уведомлений, при сворачивании приложения в логах получаю следующее сообщение

```
D/FA: Application going to the background
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

После чего в течении минуты сервисы прекращают свою деятельность и вызывают `onDestroy()`. Как продолжать работу после сворачивания как в других плеерах?

Comment: По умолчанию сервисы работают в том же потоке, что и основное приложение, поэтому используйте потоки

Comment: Например использовать Thread? И как именно организовывать, можно пример?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru

Comment: Посмотри в сторону foreground service